# How to calculate PSNR between two 3D objects

Tags: matlab, visual-c++

Please can you help me to calculate PSNR between two 3D objects having different number of vertices. I know that it is 20log (BB)/MSE but how can I implement it using Matlab or Vc++.

Comment: Do you mean how to implement the equation you wrote in your question?

Comment: I mean how can I do this and my objects have different sizes?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us some work, as you seem to be asking some trivial question without any effort

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow.  PSNR is reserved for measuring the quality between a noisy signal with a clean signal.  How can you apply this to objects?  Are the objects themselves 3D signals?

Answer (score 0):

Ok assume that you have 3D matrixes:A_original, A_reconstructed with sizes a x b x c
Then you simply do a subtraction

```
Difference = A_original - A_reconstructed;
```

Then you raise all elements pointwise

```
Difference = Difference.^2;
```

Then you are doing sum or adding all errors

```
error = sum(sum(Difference));
```

Then `your MSE = error/(a*b*c);`

Then use your formula that you've written above.

Is it answer to your question?
Hope I helped you=)

Comment: Thank you but the problem is that the difference must be calculated using the number of vertices for example n. I must clculate the sum of  square of distances going from 1 to n .but Here I have two objects having different numbers of vertices.